# What's with the fire on Stormbreaker?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I am aware of the new uru weapon in *Avengers: Infinity War*, the Stormbreaker, and how it can summon the bi-frost etc. But what's with the fire around it? Is it not supposed to have lightning/sparks around it, like Thor's fingers? Any idea or comic reference for that?

[image]

Comment: It was kind of burning  electricity

Comment: Had he just landed at this point after travelling using the built in Bifrost travel ability? We've not seen any evidence of what would happen to a weapon that could be used to travel via the Bifrost. It could be that the "power" part of the weapon gets hot or requires to discharge the energy via heat and light (fire).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's really a fire or flame, I see this more as blue aura.

And blue aura means something powerful and/or magical.

The Stormbreaker is very powerful, hence the blue aura is expected.

Comment: Thor himself is a powerful being, but we see no blue aura for him.. (just a thing popped onto my head, probably your answer is right)

Comment: @Vishwa [no blue aura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beQ8n.png)? ;-)

Comment: That's thunder,or caused by thor summoning thunger. not aura. right?

Comment: I think it would be useful to cite another example in the MCU where we see something with aura representing something powerful and/or magical.. That would probably help support your answer.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 good point, will look for such a thing.